# Looping @font-face in Stylus css

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, stylus

Let's say I declare a hash like this:

```
--font = {
    open-sans: "OpenSans",
    bebas-neue: "BebasNeue",
    uni-sans-thin: "UniSansThin",
    uni-sans-heavy: "UniSansHeavy",
    uni-sans-thin-italic: "UniSansThinItalic",
    uni-sans-heavy-italic: "UniSansHeavyItalic",
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to loop through the fonts and do a @font-face on them.

Here's an example implementation:

```
for key, value in --font
  @font-face
    font-family: value
    src: url("../assets/fonts/" + {key} + ".otf") format("opentype")
```

However this isn't working and my guess is that stylus is not able to loop through because of the '@font-face' instead it throws this error:

> expected "indent", got "atrule font-face"

My question is if this is even possible, and if not is there another way? The reason for this is because I would like to be DRY as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured it out. I was doing the interpolation all wrong. It is suppose to be like this:

```
for key, value in --font
    @font-face
        font-family: value
        src: url("../assets/fonts/" + value + ".otf") format("opentype")
```

And I was also using spaces instead of actual tabs so that contributed to my issue. I'm really glad to see that this was possible!